# Highcharts hover point shows previous point's tooltip

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

The mouse is on a data point, and the tooltip that appears belongs to a data point two or three datapoints before. 
[image: example]

Any ideas what is wrong?
I'm using Angular 1.5 and highcharts-ng.
As requested, I am attaching the Configuration (I took that from $scope.chartConfig, after the chart has loaded)

```
{  
    "options":{  
        "subtitle":{  
            "text":"Subtitle"
        },
        "chart":{  
            "type":"spline"
        }
    },
    "xAxis":{  
        "categories":[
        ]
    },
    "series":[  
        {  
            "name":"Total",
            "data":[...],
            "id":"series-13"
        },
        {  
            "name":"name",
            "visible":false,
            "data":[...],
            "id":"series-14"
        },
        {  
            "name":"name",
            "visible":false,
            "data":[...],
            "id":"series-15"
        },
        {  
            "name":"name",
            "visible":false,
            "data":[...],
            "id":"series-16"
        },
        {  
            "name":"name",
            "visible":false,
            "data":[...],
            "id":"series-17"
        },
        {  
            "name":"name",
            "visible":false,
            "data":[...],
            "id":"series-18"
        },
        {  
            "name":"name",
            "visible":false,
            "data":[...],
            "id":"series-19"
        }
    ],
    "loading":false,
    "title":{  
        "text":"Evolution"
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it would help if you showed your highchart config code

Comment: I changed the question and now you can see the chart as it goes to `config="JSON"`

Comment: Could you make sure your size is 100%? I mean no browser/CSS zoom. It may be [this bug](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/2405).

Comment: Yeap, that's the problem. Thanks a lot! PS: Make it an answer so I can accept!